# Trying to create a new object from a class using a string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

I have a class called Player, in which I have three variables, one of which is a string array (playerInv) with ten values. How do I create a new Player in my main activity class using this Player class, with each index in the array having a null value ("")?

The Player Class:

```
public class Player {

    private int playerPos;
    private int playerHP;
    private String playerInv[];

    Player(int startPos, int startHP, String[] newInventory[]) {
        playerPos = startPos;
        playerHP = startHP;
        playerInv = newInventory[10];
    }

    public int getPlayerPos() {
        return playerPos;
    }

    public void setPlayerPos(int playerPos) {
        this.playerPos = playerPos;
    }

    public int getPlayerHP() {
        return playerHP;
    }

    public void setPlayerHP(int playerHP) {
        this.playerHP = playerHP;
    }

    public String setPlayerInv(int pos) {
        return playerInv[pos];
    }

    public void setPlayerInv(String inventory) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.playerInv[i] = playerInv[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Initializing the Player in the Main Activity

```
public void setupPlayer()
{
    thePlayer = new Player(0,100,);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to have a null values or "" (empty Strings) in your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the beginning there is an error in your classes constructor.
It should look like this if you want to get the String array as a constructor parameter:

```
Player(int startPos, int startHP, String[] newInventory)
{
    playerPos = startPos;
    playerHP = startHP;
    playerInv = newInventory;
}
```

Or it should look like this, if you want `playerInv` to be always an String array with size 10.

```
Player(int startPos, int startHP)
{
    playerPos = startPos;
    playerHP = startHP;
    playerInv = new String[10];
}
```

Then you create a new `Player` object with simple:

```
thePlayer = new Player(0, 100);
```

What is important, in the second case playerInv variable would contain reference to array of type String filled with null. So the table will look like this:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

If you would like to have an array filled with empty String ("") values that looks like this:

```
   ["","","","","","","","","",""]
```

Then you also have at least 2 ways of doing this:

```
Player(int startPos, int startHP)
{
    playerPos = startPos;
    playerHP = startHP;
    playerInv = new String[10];
    Arrays.fill(playerInv, "");
}
```

Or you can use this constructor:

```
Player(int startPos, int startHP, String[] newInventory)
{
    playerPos = startPos;
    playerHP = startHP;
    playerInv = newInventory;
}
```

And do this when creating a new `Player` object:

```
String[] inventory = new String[10];
Arrays.fill(inventory, "");
Player thePlayer = new Player(0, 100, inventory);
```

Comment: Done! :) Another problem I'm having is that my thePlayer.getPlayerInv and thePlayer.setPlayerInv are coming up as "cannot resolve symbol" in my main activity. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a method `getPlayerInv()` in your `Player` class. I suggest using IntelliJ, Eclipe or Netbeans IDE when writing code in java, because they will give you error suggestions on the fly. :)

Comment: I have since corrected this. However, I still get "cannot resolve symbol" on both Get and Set methods :/

Comment: I'm sorry, but to answer this question I would need to see whole your code. Most possibly any IDE will help you fix your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Player constructor:

```
Player(int startPos, int startHP, String[] newInventory)
{
    playerPos = startPos;
    playerHP = startHP;

    if (newInventory == null)
    {
        playerInv = new String[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < playerInv.length; i++)
        {
            playerInv[i] = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        playerInv = newInventory;
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
thePlayer = new Player(0,100,null);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor that makes what you want by default.